# unable to "conda install 'anything' " with Anaconda3 ver 4.3.1 on Windows 10 x64 computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I just bought a new Win10 laptop and installed Anaconda 4.3.1 which has the default Python 3.6. According to your instructions on: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs, I should be able to install Python 3.5.2 with the following command in the Anaconda prompt window - `conda install python3.5.2` but I keep getting error messages that this url can not be found, even after frequent retries. The exact error message is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\clive> conda install python=3.5.2
Fetching package metadata ...

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/win-64/repodata.json
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate',
'certificate verify failed')],)",),),)
```

How do I install Python 3.5?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: The firewall which comes with Windows 10, ally

Answer (score -1):

add 
`ssl_verify: False`
in .condarc